# Restart the loop if file doesn't exist

Tags: python

At the beginning of a Python loop, I want the code to test if a certain file exists in the current folder, and if it doesn't, I want it to jump out and restart the loop with the next value.

I have done this before when trying to remove a file:

```
try:
    os.remove('file.txt')
except os.error:
    pass
```

Would I need to do something similar? But instead of "pass", I would "continue"?

Obviously I am not trying to remove a file now, I just want to see if it exists. Thank you!

Comment: os.path.exists() obviously...simple Google question....

Comment: Upvotes for letting other people do basic Google research?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
os.path.exists()
```

for checking if your file exists.

Answer (score 6):

You are better to just use the exception handler. If you check the file and then try to delete it, you may get an exception anyway if something else deletes the file just after you check

```
for filename in filenames:
    try:
        os.remove(filename)
    except os.error:
        pass
```

checking for existance of the filename is done like this

```
for filename in filenames:
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        ...
```